# what is the difference between Bluetooth service discovery and device inquiry?

Tags: windows, winapi, service, bluetooth

I am using win32 sockets to develop a Bluetooth application. But I see that on the msdn they have:

•Bluetooth and WSALookupServiceBegin for Device Inquiry
•Bluetooth and WSALookupServiceBegin for Service Discovery

What is this service discovery? I mean if I have a Bluetooth device it should provide Bluetooth serivce right? Or am I confusing things here?

Could someone please explain this?

I would like to get a good understanding before starting any kind of coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this service discovery? I mean if I have a Bluetooth device it should provide Bluetooth serivce right?

Yes. In order to use Bluetooth technology, a device must be compatible with the subset of [Bluetooth profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) necessary to use the desired services.

Think of it as IP and Port numbers. While you need the IP (Bluetooth device) to connect to a host, you still need the Port (Bluetooth service) in order to connect and use the host. A Bluetooth service will tell you the capability of the device and what it can do.